# "Unable to create XXX-Info.plist" building using Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, xcodebuild

When I build my project from within Xcode or using XCodeBuild it builds ok, also I can create an archive within Xcode.

However when I try to build it using Jenkins and the Jenkin's xcode plugin everything builds but then during the ipa generation stage there is this error:

"error: Unable to create '/Users/..snip ..--$(SRCROOT)/NameOfProject-Info.plist"

What might the cause of this be?

TIA

Comment: 1. Do you use different machines to make your xcode build and jenkins ? 2. what is the value of SCROOT in your xcode project ? Is it absolute or relative ?

Comment: The workspace was originally created on a different machine then checked into Git from where the build machine pulls it. SRCROOT has not been set to anything explicit other than what XCode is setting it to - which is an absolute path. So I guess that is the problem (i.e. the path is going to be /Users/<snip>/Users/<snip>, but I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: Try editing it into a relative PATH.

Answer (score 1):

*The answer is actually given by @coffeebreaks in the comment above, I just wanted to add it here for completeness.*

In my case the fix was to set the path of the info.plist to a path that does not include `SRCROOT`, so I changed from:

`INFOPLIST_FILE = "$(SRCROOT)/ProjectName/AnotherPath/Info.plist";`

to

`INFOPLIST_FILE = "ProjectName/AnotherPath/Info.plist";`